# Can I know the memory address of RS-485 in DVP-14SS2?

Tags: memory, memory-address, plc, rs485

This is the port of DVP-14SS2 for RS-485
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXL9u.png

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to determine? 
In most instances if you are looking for addressing in most instances it should be provided by the manufacturer in their documentation.

Comment: Ya, I am looking for the addressing. However, I was unable to find any related information  in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can figure is that you have a number of addresses reachable as seen in the below snap. This was retrieved from `(04) DVP-ES2_EX2_SS2_SA2_SE&TP Operation Manual (Programming).pdf` as part of [this document bundle](https://downloadcenter.deltaww.com/downloadCenterCounter.aspx?DID=5422&DocPath=1&hl=en-US) from Delta.:

[image: RS485 Slave addresses]